# Turning an edited table within html into json, sending to django

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I have a `contenteditable="true"` table as a part of my html. I want a user to be able to edit that table and click a button to send updated data which will transform the table into JSON which I will later unwrap to a dataframe in python.  So far, I have figured how to get JSON:

```
<button onclick="table2json()">
 JSon
</button>
<script>
 function table2json(){ 
 var myJSON =JSON.stringify(makeJsonFromTable("dataframe"))
 //return console.log(myJSON)
 }
</script>
```

However, I know almost none of ajax.

In views.py, I created:

```
def gettable(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       json_data = json.loads(request.body)
       out_file = open("file.json", "w")
       json.dump(json_data, out_file)
       out_file.close()`
```

but what do I actually write in my jQuery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
 url: '/saveData' // endpoint,
 dataType: 'json', // type of data
 data: myJson // data to send,
 method: 'POST'
})
.done(function(response) {
  // do stuff with server response
})
.fail(function(error) {
  // show notification
});
```

[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) More info about ajax in jQuery

Comment: One thing to add is that `/saveData` should be defined in the django app's `urls.py` and must point to the `gettable` function.